# Error in Android: Cannot find symbol method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compile the following code but I keep getting the error.

`Cannot find symbol method toCharacterArray(string)`
`Cannot find symbol method writeSuccess(int,char[],char[])`

```
public class ControlFlow {

    char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

    public void start(){
        char[] sentenceToTest = toCharacterArray("the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog");
        char[] missingLetters = new char[26];

        int numOfMissingLetters = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < alphabet.length; i++){
            char letterToFind = alphabet[i];

            if(hasLetter(letterToFind, sentenceToTest)){
                missingLetters[numOfMissingLetters] = letterToFind;
                numOfMissingLetters++;
            }
        }

        writeSuccess(numOfMissingLetters,missingLetters,sentenceToTest);
    }

    public boolean hasLetter(char aLetter, char[] aSentence) {
        boolean found = false;
        int position = 0;
        while(!found){
            if(aLetter == aSentence[position]){
                found = true;
            }else if(position == aSentence.length - 1){
                break;
            }else{
                position++;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

waht you have to do is

```
String abc="the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog";

char[] sentenceToTest=abc.toCharArray();
```

and you dont have writeSuccess method defined in your class

```
public void writeSuccess (int numOfMissingLetters,char[] missingLetters, char[] sentenceToTest){



  Log.e("","number of missing letters are : "+numOfMissingLetters);
  Log.e("","------------------");

   for(int i=0 ;i<sentenceToTest.length();i++){

      Log.e("","sentence to test is : "+sentenceToTest[i]);

   }

   Log.e("","------------------");


   for(int i=0 ;i<missingLetters.length();i++){

      Log.e("","missing letter is : "+missingLetters[i]);

   }


}
```

Comment: awesome, that fixed that error, thank you, but now i am only getting the writesuccess error

Comment: You didn't answer the second part of the question. Also, could you explain your answer?

Comment: @BradHazelnut you havent defined your method in your class

Comment: @BradHazelnut Could you tell what this method is for writesuccess ?

Comment: from the tutorial, its just supposed write to the output log that it was a success

Comment: @BradHazelnut can you share that link so that i can see what that function is realy doing.

Comment: its a video tutorial from deltaprogram

Comment: @BradHazelnut Complete link ? :)

Comment: there is no link, its a video course that i use at my job, they put all the files on my desktop, and i watch it from there

Comment: until or unless i know what this function is for i cant help you :(

Comment: according to the video, it supposed to write something somewhere that i would be able to see using the logcat while its compilin

Comment: so what i under stand is that this function is printing some thing in the log if it is yes then i am updating my answer check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] sentenceToTest = toCharacterArray("the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog");
```

Should be:

```
char[] sentenceToTest = "the quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog".toCharacterArray();
```

`.toCharacterArray()` is a method of the String object. So you do `str.toCharacterArray()`, not `toCharacterArray(str)`.

For your second issue, you don't have a `writeSuccess()` method implemented in the code you're showing us.

Comment: @BradHazelnut Glad I could help! I'm not sure about the second problem, that code is not included in what you showed us. I could help you more with that if you show it to me. I suspect that there's a parameter mismatch.